# C++ Recognizing double digits using strings

Tags: c++, digit

Sorry, I realized that I put in all of my code in this question.  All of my code equals most of the answer for this particular problem for other students, which was idiotic.

Here's the basic gist of the problem I put:

I needed to recognize single digit numbers in a regular mathematical expression (such as 5 + 6) as well as double digit (such as 56 + 78).  The mathematical expressions could also be displayed as 56+78 (no spaces) or 56 +78 and so on.

The actual problem was that I was reading in the expression as 5 6 + 7 8 no matter what the input was.

Thanks and sorry that I pretty much deleted this question, but my goal is not to give answers out for homework problems.

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: Not entirely related to your problem but anyway: The switch and the if statements will result in the same machine code on most compilers after optimization. However your if cascade leaves the return value potentially uninitialized (your compiler should have warned you about that) and you should fix that (or use the switch statement which is correct). In general I would use the switch statement in this case as I find it more concise but thats a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: @ChrisWue Thank you for you're input.... you're right, I should return 0 or something if nothing else gets hit.  Yeah generally I just didn't know if a switch statement is faster or not, but I agree with you, switch statements look pretty cool haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it helps to move such `if`s like this

```
userInput[i] != '+' || userInput[i] != '-' || userInput[i] != '*' || userInput[i] != '/' || userInput[i] != '^' || userInput[i] != ' ' && i < userInput.length()
```

into its own function, just for the clarity.

```
bool isOperator(char c){
  return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^';
}
```

Also, no need to check that it's no operator, just check that the input is a number:

```
bool isNum(char c){
  return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
}
```

---

Another thing, with the long chain above, you got the problem that you will also enter the `tempNumber += ...` block, if the input character is *anyhing* other than `'+'`. You would have to check with `&&`, or better with the function above:

```
if (isNum(userInput[iterator])){
    tempNumber += userInput[iterator];
}
```

This will also rule out any invalid input like `b`, `X` and the likes.

---

Then, for your problem with double digit numbers:
The problem is, that you *always* input a space after inserting the `tempNumber`. You only need to do that, if the digit sequence is finished. To fix that, just modify the end of your long `if-else if` chain:

```
// ... operator stuff
} else {
  postfixExpression << tempNumber;
  // peek if the next character is also a digit, if not insert a space
  // also, if the current character is the last in the sequence, there can be no next digit
  if (iterator == userInput.lenght()-1 || !isNum(userInput[iterator+1])){
      postfixExpression << ' ';
  }
}
```

This should do the job of giving the correct representation from `56 + 78   -->  56 78 +`. Please tell me if there's anything wrong. :)

Comment: @Xeo Thank you for the help.  I'm just using your example "isOperator" because I do need to make sure that variables can be inputted (so a+b still needs to work out to a b +).  Having said that I'm getting a subscript out of range error at this last if statement you gave me... I'll try some tests with the length, it always confuses me.  But I'm pretty sure the out of bounds is because the if statement checks iterator + 1 (which means it misses the first part of the statement). Thanks

Comment: @Xeo Okay I should've done the tests before I put the last comment... sorry haha. iterator == userInput.length() needs to be iterator == userInput.length() - 1.  It almost works but now if I put 5+6 I get 5 6 + but if I put 5 + 6 I get 6 +.  likewise 56 + 78 becomes 578 + whereas 56+78 is 56 78 +.  I don't know what happened, it has to be the test with the space but it was working before.  Thank you

Comment: @Jesse: The error is your own fault for replacing the `' '` with a `'\b'`. :) When it reaches the `' '` after the `6` of `56 + 78`, it backspaces by one and deletes the `6` out of the stream. You should just ignore the `' '`. This should fix it, if I got the problem right.

Comment: I'm not understanding the "ignore" it.  I replaced it with the backspace for aesthetic appeal.  Now no matter what the output would look the same.  I tried to replace the space with a nothing char ('') but got an error.  Thank you for the help

Comment: @Jesse: With ignore, I mean don't do anything. Just take out the first if-block. :) I hope that fixes it for you, if not, report back!

Comment: @Xeo If I take out the first if statement I get too many spaces.  For example if someone puts "5 + 6" then the output would be something like "5    6 +".  I think I can figure out this part though.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The problem really consists of two parts:  lexing the input (turning the sequence of characters into a sequence of "tokens") and evaluating the expression.  If you do these two tasks separately, it should be much easier.

First, read in the input and convert it into a sequence of tokens, where each token is an operator (`+`, `-`, etc.) or an operand (`42`, etc.).

Then, perform the infix-to-postfix conversion on this sequence of tokens.  A "Token" type doesn't have to be anything fancy, it can be as simple as:

```
struct Token {
    enum Type { Operand, Operator };
    enum OperatorType { Plus, Minus };

    Type type_;
    OperatorType operatorType_; // only valid if type_ == Operator
    int operand_;               // only valid if type_ == Operand
};
```

Comment: Sorry I had to go an research what all these things were haha.  To my understanding structs are like public classes; enum places values on everything in the braces right? so operand would be 0 and operator would be 1.  Final question: would this push numbers together? such as in "56 + 78" the char 5 and the char 6 will be pushed as an int "56"?  I guess I just don't understand the last three lines.  Thank you for the quick reply